# How to configure email address for a user in Microsoft Azure AD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have created a trial account for Microsoft Azure. In Azure Active Directory, I'm trying to create a new user, but I'm not seeing email address field. I see only username, firstname, lastname and display name fields. Will Azure treat username (like testuser@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com) as an email? or I'm I missing something? I didn't find much information in its documentation.

Comment: Are you looking for a place to store email address of the user? Or are you looking for the user to actually have a mailbox?

Comment: I'm one of Ben's coworkers - we are using FIM (v 4.1.3496) and the Windows Azure Active Directory Connector. We have mail populated in our on-prem directory and flowed to the mail attribute in the WAAD connector (I can see it in the connectorspace), but it's not populating the mail attribute in Azure AD. Any ideas?

Comment: If anyone like me is troubleshooting AAD SSO and using the user.mail field - The answer lies in the email field of the user on your local AD server. I can't find anywhere in either AAD or office365 that actually reflects the user.mail field.

Answer (score 13):

No, Azure AD will not assume that the username (known as "UserPrincipalName", in the Azure AD Graph API and Azure AD PowerShell module) is actually an email address that can receive emails.

If you would simply want a place to store a given user's email address (one that actually has a mailbox behind it), you can use the "Alternate Email Address" field in the Azure Portal (under "Profile" section for a given user in your directory):

[image: Alternate Email Address]

(Note: This field is known as `otherMails` in Azure AD Graph API, `AlternateEmailAddresses` in Azure AD PowerShell v1 (MSOnline), and `OtherMails` in Azure AD PowerShell v2 (AzureAD). In all cases, it's an array of strings, not a single value.)

You can create more user-friendly usernames by adding and verifying a custom domain name to you Azure AD directory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-add-domain. Once you've done this, you can create users that have usernames such as `user@contoso.com` (assuming `contoso.com` is the domain you added).

At this point, it *may* be that `user@contoso.com` is *also* the email address of that user, but again—there is no assumption in Azure AD that this is the case.

Comment: So when is the `mail` attribute used?  Only if the user has an O365 mailbox?

Comment: Currently, `mail` is only set by Exchange Online (so yes, with an O365 mailbox), or by syncing from an on-premises directory solution to Azure AD (e.g. DirSync, Azure AD Sync, Azure AD Connect, etc.). Do you have a scenario that requires being able to set `mail`?

Comment: We're trying to sync via FIM and `mail` appears to be read-only.

Comment: I'm almost sure `mail` is settable using the FIM + Azure AD Connector.  When you say "appears to be read-only", where do you see this?

Comment: There is also an "Email" field in the Azure Portal, which can be edited. However, it seems that the `IUser.Mail` field is always empty, whereas `IUser.OtherMails` contains the "Alternative Email Address" value from the Azure Portal.

Comment: looks like that the email address that can be edited in the portal can be retrieved using the Get-MSOLUser in the .StrongAuthenticationUserDetails.Email field… quite convoluted… and i've no idea on how to edit it via powershell

Comment: Seems like the email address fields have been moved from "Profile" to "Authentication methods" in the Azure Portal.

Comment: It seems they moved things *again*, now (June 2023) it has associated an e-mail used for a support request in a different browser tab with the AzureAD account in a different browser tab, without telling me during the e-mail prompt that it would reconfigure the AzureAD account, and the actual e-mail field doesn't show up anywhere, The Profile page says to look in the Authentication page, which has no such field.  Unlike the OP, this Azure AD domain has no associated onprem domain.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into issues using with this with an Office 365 developer account, make sure you go through the entire registration process.  I thought I had completely setup my office 365 dev account, but I had missed a part related to setting up email.

Also if you are using your personal Microsoft account, for testing etc., be aware that it may appear like some things work the same as the full version or Office 365 dev, but they don't.