# Why isn'y my user created in the Azure AD using the graph API?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I use the following code to create a dummy user:

```
public void AddDummyUser(string email)
{
    var user = new User
    {
        AccountEnabled = true,
        DisplayName = "Dummy User",
        UserPrincipalName = email, // email = "DummyUser@xx.onmicrosoft.com"
        PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
        {
            ForceChangePasswordNextLogin = false,
            Password = "Demo2016!"
        },
        MailNickname = "DummyUser",
        GivenName = "Dummy",
        Surname = "User",
        JobTitle = "n.v.t.",
        Department = "n.v.t.",
        City = "n.v.t.",
        State = "n.v.t.",
        Mobile = "n.v.t.",
        UsageLocation = "US"
    };
    var adClient = GetAdClient();
    adClient.Users.AddUserAsync(user); // When I use .Wait() the application hangs and nothing happens.
}
```

I know I can connect to my Azure AD because I am able te retrieve a user by it's email. The following code is working just fine:

```
 private User GetUserByEmail(string email)
{
    /*
        OtherMails is the "ALTERNATE EMAIL ADDRESS" in Azure AD.
        Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35782771/40676
        */
    var adClient = GetAdClient();
    var userLookupTask = adClient.Users
            .Where(u => u.OtherMails.Any(m => m.Equals(email, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            .ExecuteAsync()
            .Result
            .CurrentPage
            .FirstOrDefault();

    User user = (User)userLookupTask;
    return user;
}
```

Both methods are in the same class.

What am i doing wrong here?

EDIT:

When I first call `GetUserByEmail` and then call `AddDummyUser` I see the user is being created in the Azure AD. Very, very confused about this...

Comment: I just tested your code as is and it worked for me with and without the .Wait(), and also without calling GetUserByEmail first... Are you sure it wasn't a transient thing? What's your code for GetAdClient()?

Comment: you should mark your method as async and use await