# How to add email attribute to AzureAD through powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

When I attempt to Set-AzureADUser I can't find any information on setting the Email parameter, I only have the option to set -othermails. Is there anyway to call the email parameter? I'd rather not run through the GUI for over 350 users.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0 There are no parameters for -email.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773352/how-to-configure-email-address-for-a-user-in-microsoft-azure-ad) will answer your question.

> ...the username (known as "UserPrincipalName", in the Azure AD Graph API and Azure AD PowerShell module) is actually an email address that can receive emails
>
> ...You can create more user-friendly usernames by adding and verifying a custom domain name to you Azure AD directory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-add-domain. Once you've done this, you can create users that have usernames such as user@contoso.com (assuming contoso.com is the domain you added).

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this doesn't enable email in Azure AD. Looks like the user must be licensed with an Exchange license to be able to have an email address listed in Azure AD.